# require_once problem with templating

Tags: php, filesystems

Im new to MVC and I'm re-doing a lot of my code.

I have `master.php` (index) which has:

```
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
```

Both `master.php` and `header.php` are in the same folder yet I get the following error:

> Warning: require_once(1) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/MyName/Sites/MySite/Views/master.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '1' (include_path='.:') in /Users/MyName/Sites/MySite/Views/master.php on line 15

This did not happen before. (Files were all in root folder). I don't see what the problem is though, since they are in the same folder - I don't have to go back `'../'` or reference any other folders. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: From the error it doesn't look like its trying to require "header.php" it looks like its trying to require "1". Is the line you show really on line 15? It might help if you post some more of your code

Comment: Yes, it is the exact code at line 15: <?php require_once("header.php") or die; ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your comment you say your code is:

```
<?php require_once("header.php") or die; ?>
```

please try leaving out the "or die" -> ist is not necessary, because require_once will trigger a fatal error if the file is not found.

Edit:
I tested it, leave out the "or die" and it will work.

Edit 2: Explanation why this happened:
The above code can also be written like this:

```
require_once ( ("header.php") or die() );
```

Because require_once is not a function, but a statement in php, the braces are optional, php interprets the above as a boolean expression, where the string "header.php" gets evaluated to the boolean "true". True gets cast to a string (resulting in "1"), and this string gets passed back to require once.

So the above code gets interpreted as

```
require_once("1")
```

Here is how it gets interpreted step by step:

```
(("header.php") or die()) = (TRUE or die())
(TRUE or die()) = TRUE 
(string) TRUE = '1';
```

hope this helps ;)

Comment: Without the die, the page loads but the header & footer are not present.

Comment: Hmm, are you that the header and footer actually have content to show? e.g something gets echo'd? does the page show any php-warnings?

Comment: I've looked at both header.php and footer.php directly and they both show their content fine.

Comment: please put this code before the require_once in you code:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

and tell me if there are any errors / warnings

Comment: I did it and nothing happened.

Comment: Hmm, i'm out of ideas, this kind of stuff is hard to debug without the sourcecode :/

Comment: header.php is found and includet, else php would show an errormessage. so the problem should be something else.

Comment: I think you're right smoove666 ... I'm gonna play around with some stuff and report back.

Comment: Solved, thanks a bunch sir (and everyone else for contributing, much appreciated) !

Answer (score 2):

PHP starts looking for 'header.php' in your root folder and can't find it. If it is in the same directory as the current script, you should rather use the magic constant [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
<?php require_once __DIR__ . '/header.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Since header.php and master.php are both in the same directory and the include path has '.' in it then this should not be required.

Comment: The current directory (include_path = .) is the path from which the script is called, not the directory, the script is residing in.

Comment: Then I would first solve the problem referenced in the comments to your question

Comment: @soulmerge: How are the calling directory and the directory the script is residing in different?

Comment: You can enter the following into a shell for example: php other/dir/file.php. It also happens if 'master.php' is included from a file in another directory: then the current directory is that of the including script, not that of master.php.

Answer (score 2):

It may be because `master.php` is being included or required by **another script file that is not in the same directory** as `header.php`.  That is, when you visit the index, do you know which file is being invoked/parsed?

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for `include()`, which also applies to `require()`:

> Files for including are first looked
> for in each include_path entry
> relative to the current working
> directory, and then in the directory
> of current script. E.g. if your
> include_path is libraries, current
> working directory is /www/, you
> included include/a.php and there is
> include "b.php"  in that file, b.php
> is first looked in /www/libraries/
> and then in /www/include/

**Update**

To address some of the comments: I didn't say that include() would change the CWD.  I'm saying that if the CWD is not the one where both master/header.php are located, that could be the issue.

For example, say you have `index.php` in a different folder than `master.php` and `header.php`; it includes or requires `master.php` using the proper path to it.  Now, `master.php` has the statement:

```
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
```

However, at this point the CWD *does not contain* `header.php`, since the CWD is that of `index.php`.

To fix this, you need to call `require_once` with the proper path from the CWD of the current script to `header.php`, NOT the path from `master.php`.

Comment: You can get/check/display the current working directory with getcwd(), http://php.net/getcwd . An include()/require() does _not_ change the cwd, only something like chdir() does.

Comment: I used getcwd(); and it gave me /Users/MyName/Sites/MySite    --  Therefore require_once("Views/header.php"); should work, but it does not. It gives me the same error!

Comment: Also, Peter brought up a good point above about master.php being required/included by another script not in the same directory. So I went to http://localhost/~MyName/MySite/Views/master.php and I get the exact same error!

Comment: VolkerK, please see my update, I did not say that include or require change the CWD.

Comment: Peter I tried using the CWD (/Users/MyName/Sites/MySite) : require_once("/Users/MyName/Sites/MySite/Views/header.php"); and I get the same error :(.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have line 15 as this:

```
<?php (require_once("header.php")) or die(); ?>
```

However since when header.php is not found the require is fatal then you should have:

```
<?php (include_once("header.php")) or die(); ?>
```

or

```
<?php require_once("header.php"); ?>
```